# Pushing a std::array to a std::stack

Tags: c++

I'm doing a problem where I need to create a stack of n-dimensional coordinates. I have implemented the coordinates as type `std::array<std::size_t, n_dims>`, where `n_dims` is a compile-time constant.

> **Q**: What is the best way to push a coordinate to the stack?

**Possibilities:**

1. Creating the array as a variable, then pushing it to the stack. This seems wasteful. A bit less bad if I use move semantics:

```cpp
std::array<std::size_t, 2> my_array = {1, 3};
my_stack.push(std::move(my_array));
// or my_stack.emplace(...)
```

but still unnecessarily complicated.

2. Using `std::stack::emplace`. This doesn't seem to work. I think it's because `std::array` is an aggregate type. (I'd like to understand this point better -- I believe one important consequence is that aggregate types have only default and copy constructors.)

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <stack>

int main() 
{
    std::stack<std::array<int, 2>> st;
    st.emplace(1,3);      // doesn't work
    st.emplace({1,3});    // doesn't work
    st.emplace({{1,3}});  // doesn't work
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Method 1 is not wasteful. It might hurt debug performance but that's it. Optimizer is supposed to be able to optimize such trivial inefficiencies. As aside, using `std::move` on `std::array` is completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::experimental::make_array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array)

```
#include <experimental/array>
#include <array>
#include <stack>

int main() 
{
    std::stack<std::array<int, 2>> st;
    st.emplace(std::experimental::make_array(1,3));
}
```